# POST Multiple forms with same id from javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, post

i have a little problem...i read a lot posts and i find some answers but...!i have multiple forms who created dynamically in PHP code!I have checkbox to every form and i check the forms to save the edits!my problem is when i check 3 forms only the first saved because only this post to save.php page!i make some changes to my code:

What i can do to make this code to send all forms to save.php page when i press th button save all

```
function save_all()
{
var all_elem=document.getElementsByTagName("*");
var same_id=new Array();
var index=0;
    var answer=confirm("The prices from checked products will change!Are you    sure");
    if(answer)
    {
        for(var i=0;all_elem.length;i++)
        {
            if(all_elem[i].id=="form1"){
            same_id[index++]=all_elem[i];
            document.forms[all_elem[i]].action="save_all.php";//error
            document.forms[all_elem[i]].submit();//error
            }
        }
    }


//this is my form and i have while loop to create multiple forms
<form id="form1" name="form[<?=$form_counter++;?>]" method="post" class="checkboxes">
```

Comment: Multiple elements should not have the same ID.

Comment: Ditto - Have you got the message

Answer (score 5):

First, IDs must be unique. Period.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id

Secondly, that's way too much code and very inefficient DOM traversal.

```
var forms = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
for(var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++)
{
    forms[i].submit();
}
```

But I doubt this will work. A form submittal reloads the page in some fashion. How can multiple form submissions occur at once (other than in the extremely obscure case of submitting multiple forms to different windows)?

And if they all must occur at once, why aren't they in a single form?

Answer (score 2):

First. Use unique IDs **always**

Second. You can send the forms one by one, using Ajax, with jQuery or other library you like. But better, use a single form, adding all your input fields to it. So, when you submit your form, all data will be sent to your PHP script (hint: use unique names for each of the fields, so you can identify which product they represent)

Comment: +1 for mentioning an async request (because you are technically correct). For the OP's benefit, this still probably isn't a good idea because it makes ensuring integrity across multiple requests much more difficult (e.g. form #4 fails...now what do you do? how will you roll back the changes from other forms?) It's possible but not preferable.

Comment: first of all thanks for the answers!can you see the error comments to my code?if i replace it with alert! i can count the forms which means i can read it but i can't post it!I see that many people use  this XMLHttpRequest!What is your opinion?Make id's unique or use XMLHttpRequest ?I try abjuring to change form id because i have more  javascript code and i use getElementById!And i don't know how to use getElementById if form tag code is that <form id="form[<?=$form_counter++;?>]" name="form[<?=$form_counter++;?>]" method="post" class="checkboxes">

Comment: @TimMedora you are right. It's a new pile of problems waiting :)

Comment: tasox have you tried to include all your fields in one single form?

Comment: it's complicated!because i programming a utility which takes all products from db and then user can see it,edit,save it,delete it,unpublish it!this part of code works!if i want to do this on single form!!what happens if user want to change price in 10 products?So to fix this problem i put checkbox!User change prices and then check this products!after all that must press the button to save all of it!!!but this is the problem...

Comment: Surely there is a one way! I'm sure!if i put all forms to same class??

Comment: @tasox - I would suggest marking this question as answered, and then opening a new question with your PHP code that generates these forms. Perhaps someone can suggest how to combine them into one.